# Can somebody explain i+++x?

Tags: java, increment, drjava

I was messing with `i++` when I stumbled upon `i+++[another expression]`. I went and tested it in DrJava:

```
> int i;
> i++ 
0
> i+++1
2
> i+++1
3
> i+++2
5
> i+++1
5
> ++i+1
7
> ++i+1
8
> ++i+1
9
> ++i+2
11
```

Later, I did this:

```
> int i;
> i+++(++i);
> System.out.print(i);
2
> System.out.print(i);
2
> i+++(++i);
> System.out.print(i);
4
> i+++(++i);
> System.out.print(i);
6
```

I concluded that the value that was being returned was the addition of i++ and another variable. But what about i+++(++i)? What's going on there? And most importantly, why would I want (or not want) to use this in my code?

Comment: You don't want to use it because people will ask this question, including yourself, further down the line.

Comment: Never use more than three `+` like that. If you ever want to use that, do this: `(i++)+...`. By grouping it, you make it clear to anyone who might read your code.

Comment: Note that the following is perfectly valid Java code: `int i = 0; i += +i+++-(+i++)-+(i+=+i++); System.out.println(i);` Outputs `-5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i+++(++i)
```

We can rewrite this as

```
(i++) + (++i)
```

Note that `i++` increments `i` and returns `i`'s *initial* value, whereas `++i` increments `i` and returns `i`'s *new* value.

So, for `i = 3`, `i++` increments `i` to `4` and returns `3`. `++i` then increments `i` to `5` and returns `5`. Hence, the result is `8`. `i` will have a final value of `5`, as it was incremented twice:

```
int i = 3;

System.out.println(i+++(++i));
System.out.println(i);
```

```
8
5
```

Sometimes it's helpful to view this as [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings):

```
ILOAD 1       // load i
IINC 1 1      // increment i
IINC 1 1      // increment i
ILOAD 1       // load new i (i.e. initial i + 2)
IADD          // add top two values on stack: i and (i + 2)
```

---

> And most importantly, why would I want (or not want) to use this in my code?

*Never* do something convoluted like this in your own code. Break it up into smaller, intelligible, parts, instead of doing it all on one line.

Comment: @oldmud0 I am well aware of that.

Comment: +1 for "Never do something convoluted like this in your own code". I'd fire any programmer writing anything like this, immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You would never want to use this in your code. It is so confusing and obfuscated that you had to come here and ask about it. Your sense of human empathy should lead you to conclude that you would not feel good about putting another developer through that.

As for how `i+++(++i)`, it decomposes into `(i++) + (++i)`. If `i` starts as zero, the evaluation is:

- `i++` i becomes 1 and this evaluates to 0.
- `++i` i becomes 2 and this evaluates to 2.
- `0 + 2` evaluates to 2 (not shown in your output), i is 2.

Now if `i` is 2:

- `i++` i becomes 3 and this evaluates to 2.
- `++i` i becomes 4 and this evaluates to 4.
- `2 + 4` evaluates to 6 (not shown in your output), i is 4.

And if `i` is 4:

- `i++` i becomes 5 and this evaluates to 4.
- `++i` i becomes 6 and this evaluates to 6.
- `4 + 6` evaluates to 10 (not shown in your output), i is 6.

Now `i` is 6:

- `i++` i becomes 7 and this evaluates to 6.
- `++i` i becomes 8 and this evaluates to 8.
- `6 + 8` evaluates to 14 (not shown in your output), i is 6.

It is worth noting that `a + b;` is not a valid Java statement, but Dr. Java evaluates it anyways and prints the results (which it looks like you removed in your second snippet). The side effect, though, is that i is incremented twice every time (first by `i++` then by `++i`), as you can see by the values of i derived above.

For `i+++N` the decomposition is similar: This is `(i++) + N`. Say `i` is 0 and `N` is 3:

- `i++` i becomes 1 and this evaluates to 0.
- `0 + 3` evaluates to 3, i is 1 (not shown in your output).

Now `i` is 1:

- `i++` i becomes 2 and this evaluates to 1.
- `1 + 3` evaluates to 4, i is 2 (not shown in your output).

And so on. Each time, `i` gets incremented by 1, and the expression as a whole evaluates to the previous value of `i` plus `N`.

Answer (score 2):

`i+++(++i)` can be re-written to `(i++) + (++i)`

In other words, it is the addition of a pre and post-increment of i.

However, it is so confusing and strange that it should never be used. Just use `i += 2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplify

```
int x = 0;
x++ // now 1
then
x+++1 -> (x++) + 1 -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`i+++1` => `i++` post increment `+1` add one, so it means: return i+1 and then increment i.

`i++++x` => `i++` post increment, `++x` pre-increment x ==> `(i++)+(++x)` ==> increment x, add it to i and after returning the result increment i.